# Dúvida em código Python usando Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou lendo *Head First Programming* em Python e apresentou o seguinte erro na execução de um programa proposto:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   
> File "E:\Desktop\python\teste20_Classe_tkinter.py", line 12, in <module>
>     panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav").pack()
> TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
> ```

O código é este:

```
from tkinter import*
from SoundPanel import*
import pygame.mixer

app = Tk()
app.title("Mix de Sons")


mixer = pygame.mixer
mixer.init()

panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav").pack()
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"49119_M_RED_HardBouncer.wav").pack()

def shutdown():
    mixer.stop()
    app.destroy()

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",shutdown)

app.mainloop()
```

Código da Classe:

```
from tkinter import*
import pygame.mixer

class SoundPanel(Frame):

def _init_(self,app,mixer,arq_som):

    Frame._init_(self,app)
    self.trilha = mixer.Sound(arq_som)
    self.tocar_trilha = IntVar()

    botão_trilha = Checkbutton(self,variable = self.tocar_trilha,command = self.Play_Stop,text = arq_som)
    botão_trilha.pack(side = LEFT)

    self.volume = DoubleVar()
    self.volume.set(trilha.get_volume())

    volume_scale = Scale(self,variable = self.volume,from_ = 0.0,to = 1.0,resolution = 0.1,command = self.muda_volume,label = "Volume",orient = HORIZONTAL)
    volume_scale.pack(side = RIGHT)


def Play_Stop(self):
    if self.tocar_trilha.get() == 1:
        self.trilha.play(loops = -1)
    else:

        self.trilha.stop()
        
def muda_volume(self,v):
    self.trilha.set_volume(self.volume.get())
```

Comment: Parece que o seu `_init_` está escrito com somente 1 underline, tente substituir por `__init__` e checar se funciona.

Comment: Sim, o seu `__init__` não está criado como construtor por conta do erro na sintaxe. Talvez trocando resolva o problema.

Comment: De fato há uma diferença na quantidade de argumentos da Classe e do panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer, arq_som)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existiam vários pequenos erros no código e indentação

Código da Classe:

```
from tkinter import*
import pygame.mixer

class SoundPanel(Frame):

    def __init__(self,app,mixer,arq_som):

        Frame.__init__(self,app)
        self.trilha = mixer.Sound(arq_som)
        self.tocar_trilha = IntVar()

        botão_trilha = Checkbutton(self,variable = self.tocar_trilha,command = self.Play_Stop,text = arq_som)
        botão_trilha.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.volume = DoubleVar()
        self.volume.set(self.trilha.get_volume())

        volume_scale = Scale(self,variable = self.volume,from_ = 0.0,to = 1.0,resolution = 0.1,command = self.muda_volume,
                             label = "Volume",orient = HORIZONTAL)
        volume_scale.pack(side = RIGHT)


    def Play_Stop(self):
        if self.tocar_trilha.get() == 1:
            self.trilha.play(loops = -1)
        else:
            self.trilha.stop()
        
    def muda_volume(self,v):
        self.trilha.set_volume(self.volume.get())
```

O código é este:

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame.mixer

app = Tk()
app.title("Mix de Sons")


mixer = pygame.mixer
mixer.init()

panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav")
panel.pack()
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"49119_M_RED_HardBouncer.wav")
panel.pack()

def shutdown():
    mixer.stop()
    app.destroy()

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",shutdown)

app.mainloop()
```

Eu utilizei o Anaconda então a classes estavam no mesmo documento, você vai precisar importar caso utilize em arquivos separados.

Modifiquei de :

```
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav").pack()
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"49119_M_RED_HardBouncer.wav").pack())
```

para:

```
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav")
panel.pack()
panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"49119_M_RED_HardBouncer.wav")
panel.pack()
```

---

de:

```
def _init_(self,app,mixer,arq_som):

    Frame._init_(self,app)
```

para:

```
    def __init__(self,app,mixer,arq_som):

        Frame.__init__(self,app)
```

---

de:

```
self.volume.set(trilha.get_volume())
```

para:

```
self.volume.set(self.trilha.get_volume())
```

Resultado:

[image: resultado]

Comment: Imonferrari, funcionou! Muito obrigada!. Só gostaria de saber a razão de ter acusado um erro na primeira execução referente à quantidade de argumentos no def__init__ (4 args) e a chamada no prog.principal panel = SoundPanel(app,mixer,"50459_M_RED_Nephlimizer.wav") com 3 args.   :)

Comment: O __init__ é o construtor e você tinha declarado de forma equivocada, creio que ele não estava reconhecendo um argumento que você passou.
Caso a resposta acima tenha solucionado sua dúvida, considere em marcar a resposta como válida. Obrigado!